# How to add new field in Couchbase document using GO SDK

Tags: go, couchbase, go-couchbase

The register structure below captures the data coming from the registration UI:

```
register struct {
   Email string
   Password string }
```

The collection.insert command creates the following document:

```
{  "id": "1",
   "email" : "john@example.com",
   "password" : "pwd"
}
```

The demographics struct captures the data coming from Demographics UI:

```
demographics struct {
    Name string
   Address string
}
```

I want to update the document so the resulting document is as follows:

```
 { "id": "1",
      "email" : "john@example.com",
      "password": "pwd",
      "name" : "John Doe",
      "address" : "100 Main Street"
    }
```

Using N1QL I could write the following:

```
Update bucket set name="John Doe", address="100 Main Street" where id="1"
```

I couldn't find update API in GO SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Go developer, but I think what you're looking for is called ["sub-document" operations](https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/1.6/subdocument-operations.html) in Couchbase (and it's available in all the Couchbase SDKs, including Go)

That is, the ability to insert/update/delete *parts* of a document without moving the whole thing across the wire. For instance, here's a snippet to add a "fax" field to a document (upsert creates or replaces the field as necessary):

```
bucket.MutateIn("customer123", 0, 0).Upsert("fax", "311-555-0151", true).Execute()
```

There are many subdocument options: insert, replace, exists, arrayappend, arrayprepend, etc.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working. Adding Go to my resume now :-P